# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

When I run this in the debugger, it works as expected.

```
candidateId = document.URL.split('/')[5]
fetch(URL)
.then((res) => {console.log(res); return res.json()})
.then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
    console.log(candidateId)
    var newId = res.candidateIdMap
    var value = Object.values(newId)[0]
    console.log(value)
    if (value == null) {
        return candidateId
    } else {
        return value    
    }
})
.then((candidateId) => {
    fetch(URL2)
    .then((res) => {console.log(res)})
})
}
```

However I've put it in a chrome extension and attached it to a button onClick and now I get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at content.js:63
```

That is referencing the `res` on the first `fetch()` call

```
{console.log(res); return res.json()})
```

The body is a readable stream and its returning a `200`. How should I debug this? What would cause it to break in a chrome extension but work fine in the debugger?

Comment: If the url is cross-origin, content scripts can't fetch from it in modern Chrome, see [CORB explainer](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches). Otherwise, inspect the response body in devtools and see if it's a valid json.

Comment: `How should I debug this?` - check the response is valid JSON ... the error is telling you that it **isn't**

Comment: Your code has a common error in it: You're not checking whether the request was successful. It's not just you, this is so common I [wrote it up](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) on my anemic little blog. Prior to calling `res.json()`, you need to check `res.ok`. My guess is that it's a cross-origin request that's failing, but you're trying to parse the body of the failure response (which probably isn't JSON) as JSON.

Comment: in a debugger, how do I see the body of `ReadableStream`?

Comment: @MorganAllen - It should be in the network tab.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok, the CORS makes sense. but it works when I run it myself in the debugger?

Comment: @MorganAllen - The first step is to find out why it's failing. Check `res.ok` and/or `res.status`. Also: What are `URL` and `URL2` in that code?

Comment: `res.ok` : true
`res.status` : 200

Comment: I checked the network tab and it looks like the response is empty. Howeverwhen I run the code myself, I see all of the response data. it seems like this is a CORS issue?Why is it getting blocked in a chrome extension but not when I run it?

Comment: @MorganAllen - I think the answer is in the [link wOxxOm provided](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches).